# Rationality and triangles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> Consider a triangle with angles $\alpha, 5\alpha, 180-6\alpha$. What is the minimum perimeter of that triangle, if it has integer sides and $5\alpha<90$?.

Let's call the sides that face each angle $x,y,z$ respectively, and set $\cos \alpha =t$. Using the law of sines , $x=2R\sin\alpha, y=2R\sin5\alpha, z=2R\sin6\alpha$. Setting $2R\sin\alpha=k$, we have the parametrized forms
$$x=k$$
$$y=k(16t^4-12t^2+1)$$
$$z=k(32t^5-32t^3+6t)$$

I got stuck here. If $t$ is rational, I think  we could make an argument for concluding that $t=20/21$(**Final update**: Nope, I was wrong). But that would depend on this lemma:

> If $32t^5-32t^3+6t$ and $16t^4-12t^2+1$ are rational, then so is $t$.

Is this assertion correct? If not, is there an easier way to solve the original question?

---

**Edit:**
I managed to prove that my later proposition is false when $t=\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, t=\frac{1\pm\sqrt5}4$, but true otherwise. $16t^4-12t^2+1$ is rational iff $16t^4-12t^2$ is, and then we set:
$$16t^4-12t^2=p$$
$$32t^5-32t^3+6t=q$$
$$\implies 2tp-\frac{p}{2t}=q$$
Solving for $t$, we get
$$t=\frac{q\pm\sqrt{4p^2+q^2}}{4p}$$
Substituting in the first equation with the positive case(it is analogous in the negative), we get
$$\frac{q^4}{2 p^4}+\frac{q^2}{2 p^2}-\frac{q\sqrt{4 p^2+q^2}}{2 p^2}+\frac{q^3\sqrt{4 p^2+q^2}}{2 p^4}-2=p$$
If $4p^2+q^2$ is not a perfect square, then $p=\pm q$ or $q=0$. Wolframalpha sledgehammering [both](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%2016x%5E4-12x%5E2%3D32x%5E5-32x%5E3%2B6x%2C%20p%3D%2016x%5E4-12x%5E2%2C%20q%3D32x%5E5-32x%5E3%2B6x) [cases](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%2032x%5E5-32x%5E3%2B6x%3D0%2C%20p%3D%2016x%5E4-12x%5E2%2C%20q%3D32x%5E5-32x%5E3%2B6x) (it is only necessary to check one case, since the other one corresponds to inverting  the sign of $t$), we see that that  all solutions yield rational $p,q$.

Going back to the original problem, we can forget those solutions since we wanted $0<5\alpha<90$

---

**Second update:** Substituting $2t=a/b$ with coprime $a,b$, we see that we have to minimize $x+y+z$ subject to $x,y,z$ being integers and $2\cos18<a/b<2$. Therefore, we want to minimize:
$$k\left(\left(\frac ab\right)^5+\left(\frac ab\right)^4-4\left(\frac ab\right)^3-3\left(\frac ab\right)^2+3\left(\frac ab\right)+2\right)$$
It is easy to see that when reducing to the common denominator $b^5$. the numerator will be coprime due to the leading coefficint being $1$. Therefore, $k$ must be $b^5$ in order to have integers(and not another multiple of $b^5$ since we want to minimize the perimeter). So the problem is reduced to:

> Minimize $$a^5+a^4b-4a^3b^2-3a^2b^3+3ab^4+2b^5$$
>   Subject to $a,b$ positive integers, $2\cos18<a/b<2$

Comment: I don't know if there's a smarter way, but setting the right expression equal to something can easily be solved for $t$. Next you could substitute in the left expression a see what it gives. In any case the system will be reduced to one diophantine equation in two variables, which I personally feel more comfortable with.

Comment: @barto We surely can do that. We can reduce the system by setting $w=y-k$, and then dividing the third equation by the second gives $$\frac{z}{w}=2t-\frac{1}{2t}$$. This is a quadratic in $t$, and we could solve and replace in one of those equations, and then squaring as needed to eliminate square roots. But I don't think a nice diophantine would come out of that.

Comment: Even if there exists some miraculous irrational $t$ such that both expressions are rational, then there exists a sequence $t_n$ of rational numbers with $t_n \to t$. Since $x,y,z$ need to be integers, I think you can assume that $t$ is rational.

Comment: @PedroM. I see why there would be such a sequence, but how can we conclude that $t$ is rational more formally? Just to avoid things like assuming that $x$ is rational in $x^2=2$...

Comment: @chubakueno: you're right, my argument doesn't quite cut it; not sure if that approximation idea can be of help. Anyway, this is a very interesting problem!

Comment: @PedroM. As it turns out, the proposition was false on a finite number of cases!

Comment: Didn't we just have this problem a couple of days ago, but with $a,3a,180-4a$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have not been around here for a while, do you have the link?

Comment: No, I tried to find it but failed.

Comment: Are you sure it used $\alpha$ as variable? [Google dorks can be of use here](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3A+stackexchange.com+\alpha%2C+3\alpha+integer+sides&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=site:math.stackexchange.com+\alpha%2C+3\alpha+integral+sides+triangle). And thanks for the interest!

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember what letter was used for the variable; just that the question asked for minimizing the perimeter of an integer triangle with one angle 3 times another.

Comment: Found it! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115813/triple-angle-condition

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the difference in degrees makes this harder(at least for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the problem! for shortness, let's set $2\cos18=x$. From the inequalities $a\le2b$ and $2\cos(18)b\le a$, we see the trivial inequalities:
$$a^5\ge(xb)^5,a^4\ge(xb)^4, -a^3\ge-8b^3,-a^2\ge-4b^2,a\ge xb$$
So
\begin{align*}
P(a,b)&=a^5+a^4b-4a^3b^2-3a^2b^3+3ab^4+2b^5\\
&\ge b^5(x^5+x^4-32-12+3x+2)\\
&\approx 1.69549b^5
\end{align*}
If $b\ge15, P>1287512.71875\implies P\ge1287513$. We now have an upper bound on the minimum $P$. Since we want $2\cos18<\frac ab\le \frac{2b-1}{b}<2$, we get that $b>(2-2\cos18)^{-1}>10$, so $b\ge 11$. Finally, we are left to try the pairs $a,b$ that meet the requirements and compare the $P$ that corresponds to each pair. So we calculate 
$$P(21,11)=1224640$$
$$P(23,12)=1972355$$
$$P(25,13)=3046536$$
$$P(27,14)=4543825$$
So the minimum perimter of the proposed triangle is $1224640$, with $t=21/22$ and not $20/21$ as initially hypothesised.